# Calling Convention Name Mangling in C

Tags: c, visual-c++

**What I ask is NOT how to disable C++ name mangling (i know its extern "c"). The question is not about C++**

As far as i know, when i declare a function as __stdcall its name should be mangled like in _FuncName@8 (for two int parameters). When I declare a function as __cdecl it should be mangled like in _FuncName.

Sounds fine but is it really like this?

There are two cases that I don't understand:

1-) I'm making a dll in vc++2013 and I use __declspec(dllexport) on a __cdecl function. its exported without any underscore (just FuncName). I don't have a .def file or anything and not using pragma export.

2-) Most of Windows API functions are __stdcall. But they don't have _ or @. For example they are exported like MessageBoxA without any mangling.

So how can this be explained?

Comment: C doesn't need name-mangling, so I assume you are talking about C++.

Comment: It does need and uses it. Your assumption is wrong.

Comment: Maybe Microsoft built the functions using a .DEF file?  I build DLL's all the time, I use a .DEF file, and my exported names are "clean" of any extraneous "features".

Comment: You can use a module definition file to get full control over exported names.

Comment: _"Although name mangling is not generally required or used by languages that do not support function overloading (such as C and classic Pascal), they use it in some cases to provide additional information about a function."_. [Wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Name_mangling)

Comment: "**the question is not about C++**" but you decided to tag it C++ anyway?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes, Visual C++ adds [name decoration](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/deaxefa7.aspx) to C symbol exports, as well as name mangling of C++ exports. You can read up on the name decoration conventions on MSDN in the topics for each calling convention keyword. The `extern "C"` linkage specification actually switches the exported symbols from C++ name mangling to C name decoration, which surprises people from time to time.

So in the case of a C file that exports a function, if you read the documentation on MSDN for [__cdecl](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/zkwh89ks.aspx) very, very closely, you'll see that it mentions that the "Underscore character (_) is prefixed to names, **except when __cdecl functions that use C linkage are exported**." This still isn't as clear as it could be, since "exported" here refers to DLL export, and it also applies to non-function symbols such as exported data. This is what you're seeing in your own code.

My speculation is that these names are undecorated for DLL export in order to make language interop easy. You'll note that the linkage symbol name exports still have the leading underscore, which you can see if you dump the exports of the .lib file.

As for the second case, the `__stdcall` Windows API functions are exported with specific names using .def files. That's how you get the default name mapped to the narrow- and wide-character versions of the APIs, too. You can get the same effect with `#pragma comment(linker, "/export:alias=_original")`, but it's probably most portable to use the .def file approach.

You can find a story about [The history of calling conventions](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/oldnewthing/archive/2004/01/02/47184.aspx) on Raymond Chen's *[The Old New Thing](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/oldnewthing/)* blog.

Comment: Does this mean C library functions are also exported without underscore? for example printf instead of _printf ?

Comment: Have you tried running `link /dump /exports` on msvcr120.dll (or whatever version you're using) and msvcrt.lib? The DLL version exports `__cdecl` symbols without the leading underscore, while the static library has them. (This may be hard to see, given that about half of the CRT function names actually do start with one or more underscores.) That's not surprising, since static libraries are basically collections of object files, and the symbols in the object files follow the name decoration rules. The linker does the right thing when you link with either one.

Comment: This is probably the page (Web Archive): http://web.archive.org/web/20040506125641/http://weblogs.asp.net/oldnewthing/archive/2004/01/02/47184.aspx _Function name decoration consists of a leading underscore. My guess is that the leading underscore prevented a function name from accidentally colliding with an assembler reserved word. (Imagine, for example, if you had a function called "call".)_